# Should I stay working as an Intern more than I have to?

Tags: internship, resignation

Sorry if something is written wrong. I'm a native Spanish Speaker.

I am a student of the last semester of computer engineering and in my university they ask for 6 months of being a pre professional practitioner who is similar to being an intern but they  pay you.

They pay me almost double of what is the minimum salary, which is what companies normally pay the practitioners here, in two weeks I would have completed the 6 months, the company in which I am works with banks, I work as a developer, using some software from India that for security issues, I can not google because there is no information, but what bothers me is that there is no internal documentation, it is not structured as a web application, they never trained me, is not about the language or the "normal" programming skills that someone would need,it is very old and I cant learn it anywhere because of how is made, I am thinking about quiting.

I approached the boss and talked to him, but as I do not have much experience I was not very firm with saying that I wanted to quit, so he offered to change me from client to another bank where he says that I will learn many things because there they use another application from the same software that is more structured in .NET, I am good in Java therefore, .NET is easy for me, and I accepted it but we agreed that in December we would sit and talk about it again, but I told him "I can stay until the end of September or the end of the year", but he only listened the "end of the year" part.

I had already commented what was bothering me to my supervisor for months but nobody did anything because they are very busy, other practitioners like me or the co-workers dont help me much, and when they do, they do it annoyed, money does not matter much now to me because I do not need it, and I get bored every day to do nothing.

My meeting with my boss wasnt formal at all, we just sat in a room and talked, and I do not have a contract because they dont make us sign one as "interns".

I add this: My question about quitting is after I complete the 6 months, not now. I will finish the 2 weeks, but they have already told me they want me to stay.

Comment: " in two weeks I would have completed the 6 months". What do you think to gain by quitting? You gain absolutely nothing as far as I can see. Do the last two weeks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are working on unusual software that's not well documented you may be able to make a lot of money because you will have skills not many other people can offer. But if not many companies use the software then you may have difficulty using the experience to apply for different jobs later. You should look at news.ycombinator.com where this kind of problem is discussed quite often.